# Why are P and T waves curved and not straight (ECG)

Tags: human-biology, electrocardiography

The P and T wave are in shape of a curve while the QRS complex is in straight lines.
What is the reason this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

**P wave** represents **atrial depolarization** (hence atrial contraction).

Atrial depolarization takes only a split second, therefore its corresponding wave will be smooth and rounded.

Variations from this shape could be consequences of various heart diseases: for example,a spiked P wave is called *P pulmonale* and [suggests right atrial enlargement](http://www.onlinejacc.org/content/23/3/747.abstract).

**T wave** represents ventricular repolarization: a normal T wave looks like an

> upright low amplitude broad hump following the QRS complex.

Abnormalities in T wave could be the signs for multiple heart diseases, varying from myocardial ischemia to hyperkalemia.

In particular, peaked T waves suggest an hyperkalemia diagnosis.

T wave abnormalities are well documented [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK538264/)

The **QRS complex** corresponds to **ventricular depolarization**, which is faster and more intense than atrial or ventricular repolarization: hence a normal QRS complex is peaked.

In conclusion, P wave and T wave are rounded because these correspond to low-intensity electrical events while the QRS complex is provoked by an intense electrical event.